# Drawing image on a form using Graphics.DrawImage()

Tags: c#, image, graphics, gdi+

i'm trying to draw an image on a form in front of all the other controls.
i tried to make a transparent panel infront of the controls but it only shows the background and the controls are not shown.
my code is that : (i'm using it to make a fading effect)

```
Player1ColorMatrix.Matrix33 = Player1Transparency;

Player1ImageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(Player1ColorMatrix,
                    ColorMatrixFlag.Default,
                    ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Player1ScoreImage, Player1rect, 0, 0, 200, 62, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, Player1ImageAttributes);
    Player1Transparency = 0.0f;
```

player1scoreimage is the image and player1rect is the rectangle in which i want to paint the image

how do i make this image to be in front of the other controls?

thanks,
ofir

Comment: And why can't you use an Image control?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom panel for that:

```
private class PanelX : Panel
{
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
    get
    {
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
      cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
      return cp;
    }
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0)))
    {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
    }
  }
}
```